# gedit won't save&quit after upgrade to 16.04

Tags: 16.04, gedit

Step to reproduce:

- open a text file in **gedit**
- modify something
- close the file, the program will ask to save
- say yes, the program will not exit, just save the file

Until **15.10** the beavhiour was correct.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this is the same bug as reported here on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1575454 . According to a comment, it should be fixed upstream in the next version.

Comment: I can reproduce. However, this is not a bug tracker or reporting platform. Maybe it should be reported here https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known bug:

- [Launchpad: Gedit didn't close after saving a new file](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gedit/+bug/1575454)

which has a fix released upstream:

- [Bug 734068 - gedit should quit after saving through "Save before closing?" dialog](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=734068)

An annoying bug that at the moment has only recompiling and patching as an option.  Patch is [here...](https://bug734068.bugzilla-attachments.gnome.org/attachment.cgi?id=326120)